# Is Windows RPC (port 135) secure enough for domain-wide access

Tags: firewalls, windows-10

I have a network of approximately 150 computers that I'd like to regularly monitor. My proposed way of doing so involves running remote commands like `reg query \\<ip>` or `systeminfo /S <ip>`. I currently cannot do this, as the majority of the computers have the RPC service blocked in their firewall. What I cannot find clear info on is, **is safe to allow a domain-level exception for RPC (port 135) for my whole network?**

My main fear is that, if someone were to get into our private network, would this grant them an easier traversal than if this exception weren't in place?

Comment: Would an alternative be to make the domain controller push out a task that is executed on the hosts? It could potentially be added as logon script.